# I am having trouble with the streamlit I am using a Chromebook and cant keep to insert images

Tags: python, image, file, insert, streamlit

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie

#find more emojis at the link he set line 4 will show how your website would be layedout for users to see
st.set_page_config(page_title="My Webpage", page_icon=":tada:", layout="wide")

def load_lottieurl(url):
    r =requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        return None
    return r.json()    

#lottie files are for animation to be put on your webiste (pip install requests)(pip install streamlit-lottie)(pip install pillow)
lottie_coding = load_lottieurl("https://assets7.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_2znxgjyt.json")
img_william = Image.open("images\william.png")
img_tacos = Image.open("images\tacos.png")
#header section / st.container will organize the code it will work fine without 
with st.container():
    st.subheader("hello i am william and this is my first website made by python header :wave:")
    st.title("this would be were the title would go ")
    st.write("this would be a small paragraph you wold write this area")
#st.write is for small paragrahps / st.title is to start the paragraps )

# what i am doing with  the 3 lines and quotes  on line 15 and that i am diving space on the website 
with st.container():
    st.write("---")
    left_column, right_column = st.columns(2)
    with left_column:
         st.header("this will be the column for the left side ")
         st.write('##')
         st.write(
            """
            i am currently doing what the tutotial is telling me to do even though i am quite cofnused:
            - i will master this and i will understtand the concepts  of making a website with this framework 
            - i will be great i bless god for changing how i act and i am as  a person 
            - i know allot of people do not want to see me win but god does and thats all i need
            - rome was not built in a day and they will say the samething about my journey 

            i am confused but if i keep puttingand effort in everyday i will master this in jesues name
            "
```

""
)

i am having difficulty uploading images to python I am using the framework called streamlit and i have been following a tutorial on how to make my own website and when i do what he does to upload the image it tells me in the terminal that no such file in the directory i have made a file for the images that includes the code in the same file so i am very confused please help i am also using a chromebook

Comment: I didn't find in your code the command st.image(img_william, "caption") and st.image(tacos, "caption"). You should use this command to show images on Streamlit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Where who I put it

Comment: You're welcome. Since the images are outside of a function, you can put them wherever you want to display it.

Comment: I just tried and still get the same error

Comment: Change "images\william.png" and "images\tacos.png" to the whole path of the images and use double \\ instead of single \. If still doesn't work, please provide the log error.

Comment: Are you just telling me to put 2 \ for the “imageswilliam.png” and out put (img_william, "caption" because that’s not working either I’m still getting the same pop up that the file does not exist

Answer (score 0):

if images folder is in the working directory and you want to display the images, all you need is the code below.

```py
st.image("images/william.png")
st.image("images/tacos.png")
```

but displaying image with PIL, you can do the following

```py
img_william = Image.open("images/william.png")
img_tacos = Image.open("images/tacos.png")

st.image(img_william)
st.image(img_tacos)
```

Then apply this last method:

1. right click on your images folder and copy full path.

```py
from pathlib import Path

SCR_DIR = 'C:\\users\\Desktop\\images' # Edit 'C:\\users\\Desktop\\images' with the coppied path you made at the first step. But maintain \\ when editting

img_william = Image.open(Path(SRC_DIR, "william.png"))
img_tacos = Image.open(Path(SRC_DIR, "tacos.png"))

st.image(img_william)
st.image(img_tacos)
```

Your scr_dir hould be something like

```py
SCR_DIR = 'C:\\user\\My files\\Webpage\\images'
```

I am pretty sure you are missing something out.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response but this did not work I tried both paths

Comment: Can you write to me what the error is?

Comment: It’s the same error No such file or directory

Comment: I edited my answer, you can apply the last method to see if it works.

Comment: **Path** starts with capital **P** and maintain \\ when editting the src_dir

Comment: It is I just copied and pasted

Comment: lets do one last thing. right click on your images folder, scroll through the pop up menu, you will see **copy path**, click on it to copy full path and paste it here in the comments for me to see.

Comment: My files/Webpage/images/tacos.png

Comment: check at the bottom of my answer. I expect your path to have C:\\user\\. Its not a good practise to have directory with space like **My files** you should write **my_files** instead.

Comment: I’m new this is one of my first projects that is the file the photos are in the names are william.png and tacos.png

Comment: What I shared with you are the steps to debug your errors. I am sure you are not applying the rules right.